# Access Mongodb from windows which installed in ubundu server

Tags: mongodb

Is there any open source GUI tool to access mongodb installed on Ubuntu Server from a windows machine for administrative and development tasks?

Comment: Try robomongo http://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of options available
look at the following link
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

.I prefere [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/)